# Unexpected token n in JSON at position 0 swagger-axios-codegen

Tags: reactjs, axios, nestjs, swagger-codegen

i cant use deleteOne function of swagger axios codegen even though i tried below BE and postman is still running

I tried to install the version from the old to the newest and it can't be used
[image][image]

Comment: Share your base path. Could be some typo.

Comment: my localhost bro

Comment: it's clearly saying that there is an unparsable \n in whatever you are trying to parse, take a closer look again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I managed to fix it by adding this axios interceptor to check if the body is null make it {}, make sure to add it to the base file like `index.jsx/tsx` or `main.jsx/tsx`

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    if (config.data === null) config.data = {};
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);
```

You can find more related to axios interceptors [here](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors)